# How to find the position and score of Sliding Window over image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

In my object detection problem I need to make different sizes sliding window for each image. Then I have to find there positions and scores. How to do it in MATLAB? Could someone kindly help me?

Answer (score 0):

Generally people create an image pyramid and have a sliding window detector. In that, they translate the detector by one pixel, left to right and top to bottom and compute detection score over the whole image followed by non-maximal suppression. Size of the sliding window depends on the aspect ratio of your detector, the minimum size of the object you want to detect, and then you can run it at multiple scales to detect bigger objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you show me an example as you explained. I will be grateful to you.